# Missing step in proof of Fund. Th. of Algebra

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

In my field theory class, we developed some basic Galois theory and used it to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra: $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed. Afterwards, I tried to recreate the proof to make sure I understood it, but there are a couple of parts I am unclear on. They are:

"It is sufficient to show that $\mathbb C$ has no proper finite extension, because then adjoining arbitrary roots to $\mathbb C$ leaves us in $\mathbb C$." (I'm not sure this is legitimate reasoning)

I proceed by saying E is a finite extension of $\mathbb C$, and that E' is its Galois closure. Then I say that if we can show $E'/\mathbb C$ is a finite extension then it follows that we could have said WLOG $E/\mathbb C$ is Galois. But I've been unable to show that $E'/\mathbb C$ is finite.

Comment: I think you can use the Galois closure (extension) of a finite extension is finite, but I can't see so far how would this help you out about the part between quotation marks (Wich, by the way, I think is accurate).

Comment: Yes, that is trivially what the same thing as what I write in the second part. The question is how to prove the closure is finite.

Comment: I think you missed what I said: **if** you can use/know that the Galois closure of a *finite* extension is itself a finite extension then you're done. But it never mind: what did you do in your class to cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \in \mathbb{C} [x]$ let $E$ be the spliting feild. $$[E:\mathbb{C}]=deg(f)<\infty$$ so acording to what you said $E=\mathbb{C}$ which mean that all of $f$ root are in $\mathbb{C}$ and that iis why $\mathbb{C}$ is algebric close. Q.E.D

Comment: Right, so if you read my post you'll notice that I asked about two specific steps in the proof. The overall structure of the proof is clear to me. I just need to figure out how to show that the Galois closure of a finite extension is a finite extension.

Comment: If you take $f$ irreducibld polynom that $f$ is also have nk double root (the argument with $gcd(f,f')$) so the spliting field is a Galois exstenstion.